# Join/merge 3 tables with count

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, merge

I have 3 tables:

people:

```
pid    name
1      Cal
2      Example
3      Another
4      Person
```

talkingPoints:

```
tid    pid    talkingPoint
1      1      "..."
2      1      "..."
3      2      "..."
```

facts:

```
fid    pid    fact
1      3      "..."
2      2      "..."
```

**And I'm trying to combine a count of talkingPoints and facts to 'people', for example:**

```
pid    name     talkingPoints  facts
1      Cal      2              null
2      Example  1              1
3      Another  null           1
4      Person   null           null
```

(ordered by talkingPoints desc, then alphabetical, including 'people' rows which do not have any values for the counts)

I managed to combine 'people' with only one other table:

```
SELECT a.pid,a.name,
count(b.tid)  
FROM people a, talkingPoints b  
WHERE a.pid=b.pid  
GROUP BY b.pid;
```

but that query ignores rows with a zero count (e.g. the row 'Person')

I hacked up this query which works correctly for 'talkingPoints' but I have not been able to adapt it to also combine 'facts' like my example table above.

```
select people.pid, people.name, x.talkingPoints from people left join 
(select pid, name, count(name) talkingPoints from 
(select people.pid, people.name from people
join talkingPoints on talkingPoints.pid = people.pid)
 as talkingPoints group by talkingPoints.pid)
 as x on x.pid = people.pid order by talkingPoints desc, people.name asc;
```

(probably a terrible way but it worked in the meantime)

How can I adapt my queries so they will output a table like my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.pid,
        a.name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT b.tid) talkingpoints,
        COUNT(DISTINCT c.fid) facts
FROM    people a
        LEFT JOIN talkingPoints b
            ON a.pid = b.pid
        LEFT JOIN facts c
            ON a.pid = c.pid
GROUP   BY a.pid, a.name
ORDER   BY a.pid
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/210eb/1)

Comment: This works great, but I actually have another column on talkingPoints: a boolean 'archived', I tried adding "WHERE b.archived<>1" to your query but then users with any archived talkingPoints are not shown in the result table - do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using independent correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause avoids the duplicates caused by the joins:

```
SELECT pid,
       name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM talkingPoints
        WHERE pid = people.pid) AS talkingPoints,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM facts
        WHERE pid = people.pid) AS facts
FROM people
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/210eb/1)</kbd>